# Use different lombok version in two maven modules

Tags: java, maven, annotations, dependencies, lombok

I have implemented my custom annotation following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-custom-annotation) article using lombok 1.14.8 and it works fine with the test project. However, the project I am going to use my annotation with already has lombok 1.18.4 dependency. When trying to build the whole project, I get errors because Maven tries to use 1.14.8 for the whole project. Is there any way to extract annotation processors compilation outside the normal Maven flow to be able to use lombok 1.14.8 for my custom annotation?

Comment: Can you attach the error? would help in understanding the exact root cause.

Comment: @kulsin some annotation processing involving features of newer versions of Lombok (e.g. @RequiredArgsConstructor) is not performed, so I get multiple different errors. Also, if I try to build only the troubled module, I get an error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lombok.javac.JavacAnnotationHandler`, meaning that only the 1.18.4 is used